# Redirect loop when using Yii ip access rule

Tags: php, yii

Using **Yii 1.1.15**. I want to restrict the login and logout actions by ip rule. I have this inside the controller:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return [
        [
            'allow',
            'actions' => ['index', 'error'],
            'users' => ['*'],
        ],
        [
            'allow',
            'actions' => ['login'],
            'users' => ['*'],
            'ips' => ['xx.yy.zz.qq'],
        ],
        [
            'allow',
            'actions' => ['logout'],
            'users' => ['@'],
            'ips' => ['xx.yy.zz.qq'],
        ],
        [
            'deny', // deny all users
            'users' => ['*'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

But when I call the login action in the browser, the browser enters a redirect loop. If I comment out the `ips` rule, it works.

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has finally proved to be a bug that exists in both 2.0 and 1.1 branches. It's already been fixed in 2.0 branch (scheduled for the 2.0.1 milestone) and I've created a pull request for the 1.1 branch.

The issue for the 2.0 branch is at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4889